# psychological / patient dialogue data for nlp analisys

Tags: data-request, medical, nlp

I search data for chatbot for psychological task.

I found some source about it:
https://berkeleysciencereview.com/nlp-for-psychotherapy/

Where can I find data with dialogue of psychologist and client in session
to create chatbot (using deep learning) which can communicate with client?

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be hard to find "big data" on this one, but one dataset would be transcripts from the "[Gloria Tapes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5errJ-u2_eg)". It's quite old, mid 1960s, but at least it's data in an otherwise extremely private sector (and rightfully so).

Here's the record for a transcription: https://www.worldcat.org/title/transcript-of-three-approaches-to-psychotherapy-a-series-of-three-16-mm-films-illustrating-three-distinguished-approaches-to-psychotherapy/oclc/36749900

---

A more extreme example would be psychiatric interview with serial killers, for example: https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/shadow-boxing/201710/the-psychologist-and-the-serial-killer

Comment: intersting question, is there  direct link on https://www.worldcat.org/title/transcript-of-three-approaches-to-psychotherapy-a-series-of-three-16-mm-films-illustrating-three-distinguished-approaches-to-psychotherapy/oclc/36749900. I would like to dowmload, but  here can't direct download link

Comment: Probably will have to request it through a library. I imagine it’s only available as a hard copy